# XForms - Separate Deployment with Portlets fails loading resources

Tags: liferay, portlet, orbeon, xforms

Having problems with filtered xform resources – javascript, css and images. We tried to show xform in liferay portlet using OrbeonPortletXFormsFilter and Trampoline servlet writing to the response whole form or with request.setAttribute(“oxf.xforms.renderer.document”, xformXml). Result is the same - form is rendered but javascript and CSS are not found and all form is scattered. Form actions doesn’t work too. Thank you.

My configuration:

portlet.xml

```
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>xForm-portlet</portlet-name>
        <portlet-class>com.xform.XFormPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>oxf.main-processor.name</name>
            <value>{http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors}pipeline</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>oxf.main-processor.input.config</name>
            <value>oxf:/config/prologue-portlet.xpl</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>oxf.error-processor.name</name>
            <value>{http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors}pipeline</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>oxf.error-processor.input.config</name>
            <value>oxf:/config/error.xpl</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Xform Portlet</title>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
<filter>
    <filter-name>orbeon-forms-portlet-xforms-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.orbeon.oxf.portlet.OrbeonPortletXFormsFilter</filter-class>
    <lifecycle>RENDER_PHASE</lifecycle>
    <lifecycle>ACTION_PHASE</lifecycle>
    <lifecycle>RESOURCE_PHASE</lifecycle>
    <init-param>
        <name>oxf.xforms.renderer.context</name>
        <value>/orbeon</value>
    </init-param>
</filter>   
<!-- Map the Orbeon portlet XForms filter -->
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>orbeon-forms-portlet-xforms-filter</filter-name>
    <portlet-name>xForm-portlet</portlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>orbeon-xforms-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonXFormsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>oxf.xforms.renderer.context</param-name>
      <param-value>/orbeon</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>orbeon-xforms-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/orbeon/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>orbeon-trampoline-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.orbeon.oxf.portlet.OrbeonTrampolineServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>oxf.xforms.renderer.context</param-name>
      <param-value>/orbeon</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>orbeon-trampoline-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xforms-trampoline</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This is probably one or more bugs, as that specific feature hasn't been worked on for Orbeon Forms 4.0.

We didn't focus much on this feature because we really wanted to encourage the use of Form Runner (whether standalone, as the full portlet, or as the proxy portlet) instead. But if I understand well you have chosen the approach to write fully custom XForms? Is there any way you can use Form Builder/Form Runner instead?

Answer (score 0):

The answer at this point is that this feature is not working with Orbeon Forms 4.0. [An issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/959) has been entered.